# Is there a way to get a RandomAccessFile from a Storage Access Framework document?

Tags: android, randomaccessfile, storage-access-framework

I am trying to open a file for writing via SAF ([Storage Access Framework](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html)).

However I need the returned document/file to be written in random-access manner. 
SAF returns me an URI. I can get an `OutputStream` from that URI via `getContentResolver().openOutputStream(uri)` or get a FileDescriptor via `getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(uri, "rw")` but I can't seem to find a way to get a `RandomAccessFile` from there. Is there any way to get a random access from there?

Comment: That's not possible at all because the approach changed with SAF. You should get two streams and use respective `FileChannel`s. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28805474/1950812